# Method used in other React component returns 'is not a function' error

Tags: reactjs

I want to run onDelete method described in App React component in Bottom component. I use props for that. I get `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onDelete is not a function`. how do I do what I want?

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }
  onDelete() {
    let word = "hi";
    console.log(word);
    return word;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello React..! {this.onDelete()}
        <br/>Time: {new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()}
        <br/><Bottom/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Bottom extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
 }
 handleDelete() { this.props.onDelete(); }
 render() {
  return(<div>
      <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
    </div>);
 }
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no properties passed to the "Bottom" component.
So, in the Bottom component, `this.props.ondelete` is undefined, i.e. not a function.

Try: `<Bottom onDelete={this.onDelete}/>` instead of just `<Bottom/>`